# shortest way to create datetime.datetime object of now

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

What's the shortest way (oneliner preferred) to create a datetime object of the current date and time?

---

I can create that object with

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime(year=y, month=m, day=d)
```

I can also get year, month, and day via `time.time()`. But that's a lot of overhead. How to write it shorter?

Comment: `datetime.now()`? `date.today()`? Did you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I would say you could use

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 13, 18, 21, 3, 82799)
```

It returns a datetime object with date and time.